# Cannot remove entry in HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bam\State\UserSettings\<key>

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

In the Windows registry I find two entries in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bam\State\UserSettings\S-1-5-21-... (my user account) pointing to files in \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Users\\Downloads\ that have been deleted.

Even after I purge the trash folder and reboot Windows I'm still unable to remove these entries from the registry using regedit.

What are these entries for and how can I delete them?

Comment: You may need to take ownership of the key to delete it... see https://www.maketecheasier.com/full-ownership-windows-registry-keys/ .*N.B.* changing the Registry can create OS issues! If the key is not a problem, think again about deleting it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find this before. Just found out myself.

Comment: In regular day-to-day operation, there is no need whatsoever for the user to directly access the registry. Are you trying to solve some problem?

Comment: NEVER EVER touch anything related to BAM service (unless you want to break your system for research). It's a kernel mode driver, named as Background Activity Moderator. Google it, you'll get the idea.

Comment: I'm amused at the flurry of horrified reactions to editing the registry. If the folks expressing those reactions only knew how many manual edits I just made to fix a badly-botched uninstall of a complex program! Hundreds, if not thousands! Arduous, but not dangerous as long as one confines one's self to deleting ONLY obsolete junk. And yes, I had to delete junk from the "BAM" service, after using Mr. Gloor's Answer below to give myself the permission to do so. So yes, regedit.exe does exist to be used, and using it is fine, if one doesn't do it unwisely.

Answer (score 4):

I still dont know what these Services\bam\State\UserSettings are good for. However I found out how to get rid of the entry.

With a right mouse click on the key I've been able to change the permission settings. After this I've been able to remove the wrong data entry.

I could do so, because the entry was in releation to an old install executable for a program that has properly been uninstalled and is no longer used. The file has been deleted some time a go and is no longer used.

Comment: When you look at the Advanced Permissions on that key, who is the Owner?